# AutoMapper change the property types with custom logic and then do the mapping for new types

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, automapper, any

I have an special type called `Any` which can hold any type of value in it (like an object type)

Consider the following:

```cs
class ADto
{
  public Any Foo { get; set; } // Foo has BDto inside of it
}

class A
{
  public object Foo { get; set; } // Foo has B inside of it
}

class BDto
{
  public string Bar { get; set; }
}

class B
{
  public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured mappings like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ADto, A>();
cfg.CreateMap<BDto, B>();
```

I use custom logic to find what type is actually in `ADto.Foo` (which is `BDto`).

If I use a custom TypeConverter:

```
public class AnyToObjectTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Any, object>
{
    public object Convert(Any source, object destination, ResolutionContext context)
{
  var underlyingType = FindUnderlyingType(source); //which in case is typeof(ADto)
  // here I need to map from ADto => A, I would like AutoMapper to do this mapping since I configured this mapping in configuration, but how?
???
}
}
```

Then how can I perform mapping `BDto` to `B` for `Foo` property like it would be done normally?

I only have an extra step in my mapping that I need to find actual underlying type!

Comment: You need a map from `Any` to `object`. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html.

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu thanx for the comment. I updated the question why that does not woek for me

Comment: You need to do a little research on the context mapper.